# What is the story of Vikramaditya's throne with 32 puppets?

Tags: vikramaditya

The great king Vikramaditya had a throne which has 32 puppets. I heard that when Bhojaraja tried to sit on the throne, each puppet told a different story about the greatness of Vikramaditya. As most of us know, one of the puppets told the famous story of "Vikram - Betaal".

How did Vikramaditya get this throne, and why did he get this throne?

Comment: I don't actual answer but you can read stories about here - सिंहासन बतीसी www.ignca.nic.in/coilnet/snbts001.htm